# Mercurial changegroup hook: repository URL

Tags: mercurial, jenkins, mercurial-hook

How can I, on a Mercurial repository server, figure out the current repository URL or at least name (subpath) in a `changegroup` — or somewhat equivalent — hook? I'm running HgWeb on IIS.

`$HG_URL` returns the `push`ers URL, not the receiving repository's. `$HG_SOURCE` only returns `serve`.

Context: I'm trying to write a `changegroup` hook for Jenkins using `/mercurial/notifyCommit?url=<url>` that tells Jenkins to perform an SCM poll, and if I can't get this to work, I have to do about 50 cURL calls (once for every repository on the server) on every `changegroup` trigger, and then remember to maintain this list in `hgweb.config` for all eternity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Ton's answer, this is what I ended up doing since I'm on Windows:

**changegroup.jenkins.cmd**:

```
@for /f "delims=\" %%a in ("%CD%") do @set TOPMOST=%%~nxa
@curl.exe "http://jenkins/mercurial/notifyCommit?url=http://hgweb/%TOPMOST%" -s -S
```

Answer (score 2):

Your hook will be executed inside the root folder of that specific repository, you can use the following command in bash to get the current folder name:

```
${PWD##*/}
```

Comment: Armed with this knowledge, see my own answer!